# VowpalWabbit Contextual wabbit generating just single action irrespective of context

Tags: reinforcement-learning, vowpalwabbit

I am using vowpalwabbit in contextual bandit settings. But I am struck with a strange issue where vowpalwabbit just generating same PMF irrespective of context. Ideally it should generate different PMFs for action selection based on different context. Here is the sample data I am using.

```
shared |Context t1=a_c t2:5 t3=a_b t4:2 t5:10
|Action arm=a1 
|Action arm=a2 
|Action arm=a3 
|Action arm=a4 
0:-5:0.09 | Action arm=a5 
|Action arm=a6 
|Action arm=a7 
|Action arm=a8 
|Action arm=a9 
|Action arm=a10 
|Action arm=a11
```

I initialized my vowpalwabbit with following setting.

```
--cb_explore_adf --cb_type mtr --epsilon 0.05
```

Here is the action distribution irrespective of context in data.

[Action Dist. in data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNg3Q.png)

[Action Dist. of Contextual Bandit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPNK8.png)

Wondering what could be the cause of vowpalwabbit saturating. Is it something with the hyperparams provided?

Answer (score 0):

`--cb_explore_adf --cb_type mtr -q CA --epsilon 0.05` worked for me.